# Should I add Microdata on the product listing page or on the product detail page?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

In our website, we have a product listing page and the product detail page. My question is should we add the Microdata attributes on the listing page or on the details page? Or should it be on both?

Is there any issue with a repeated Microdata on two different pages (one on overview and one on details page)? The detail page will have more Microdata in it, but some are repeated from the overview page.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally on both. But if you have to choose, provide it on the detail page, because search engines that offer a product rich result will of course show this for detail pages, not for listing pages.

You can convey the difference between detail and listing pages with Schema.org, too:

- On the detail page, you can use [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage)→[`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity)→`Product`.
- On the listing page, you can use [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage)→[`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity)→[`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) (where each `Product` can be specified with [`itemListElement`](http://schema.org/itemListElement)).

For each `Product` on the listing pages, provide the [`url`](http://schema.org/url) property (if you want, together with the [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) property) to link to the product’s detail page:

```html
<a itemprop="url mainEntityOfPage" href="/products/42"><!-- … --></a>
```